# to_sql() error: TypeError: expected bytes, str found

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I am trying to upload a df from pythhon to sql server

steps:

1. file imported from excel (xlsx)- **OK**
2. sqlalchemy engine- **OK**

error:
SystemError: <class 'pyodbc.ProgrammingError'> returned a result with an error set.
***expected bytes, str found***

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine 
import urllib
import pandas as pd
df.to_sql('table_name', con=engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

`df.info()` gives:

```
col1              5490 non-null int64
col2              5414 non-null object
col3              5490 non-null object
col4              5490 non-null object
col5              3921 non-null object
col6              5490 non-null object
col7              5490 non-null int64
col8              5490 non-null object
col9              5490 non-null object
col10             5490 non-null object
```

in the sql table the column types are `[int]` and `[varchar](max)`

Error traceback
TypeError: expected bytes, str found

Comment: Paste the whole error stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sulution for me was to change encoding for the df objects as following:

```
for name, values in df.iteritems():
        if df[name].dtype == 'object':
            print(name)
            print(df[name].dtype)
            df[name] = df[name].str.encode('utf-8')
            #print(chardet.detect(df[name][0])['encoding'])
    return df
```

after the encoding to utf-8 the upload to sql server was a success